# R plumber api deployment on digital ocean with swagger

Tags: r, api, swagger, plumber

I am using plumber to deploy an R api to digital ocean. It's hard to provide a reproducible example here but what I want is for the swagger endpoint to compile and be available. It works locally but not on the digital ocean server.

Locally I do this:

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb("api/plumber.R")
r$run(port=8000)
```

now the swagger docs are available at: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/__swagger__/`

When I deploy to the server as follows:

```
library(analogsea)
library(plumber)
my_droplet <- as.droplet("my_droplet")

do_deploy_api(
  droplet = my_droplet,
  path = "my_path",
  localPath = "my_local_path",
  port = 8000
)

do_forward(my_droplet, "my_path")
```

Now I go to `[my_remote_ip]/my_path/__swagger__/` I get a `404`.

Anyone know how to do this?
Much appreciated.

Comment: Good point. The `run()` call defaults to only show Swagger if you're running interactively, which is why it would work from your IDE but not on a production server. I should add this as an option to `do_deploy_api`. Can you open a ticket at https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/issues ?

Comment: FYI if you're in a pinch, you could edit the file at `/etc/systemd/system___.service` to change the `run()` call to include a `swagger=TRUE` parameter. But this would get clobbered every time you call `do_deploy_api()` and you'd have to redo it.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Jeff! I opened a ticket as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around thanks to the conversation [here](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/issues/208). After `do_deploy_api()` and `do_forward()` i then do this:

```
droplet_execute([my_droplet], {
  system("sed -i 's/pr$run(port=8000)/pr$run(port=8000, swagger = TRUE)/g' /etc/systemd/system/plumber-[my_api].service", intern = TRUE) 
  system("systemctl daemon-reload", intern = TRUE)
  system("service plumber-[my_api] restart", intern = TRUE)
})
```